# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function with custom jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a wrapper plugin for the jquery autocomplete plugin as we use it everywhere on our projects and need to globally change it at times, however whenever i reference the plugin i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` my pluggin looks like so:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.CustomAutocomplete = function (options) {
    //Settings
    alert("test");
    var settings = $.extend({
        //Defaults
        ContollerMethodLink: "",
        ReturnElement: ""
    }, options);

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var employees = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: ContollerMethodLink,
                data: { "query": request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        employees[i] = { label: data[i].Key, Id: data[i].Value };
                    }
                }
            });
            response(employees);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //fill selected customer details on form
            var id = ui.item.Id;
            $('#' + settings.ReturnElement).val(id);
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

I then call it like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#AddReportingEmpText').CustomAutocomplete({
            ReturnElement: "AddReportingEmpId",
            ContollerMethodLink: "@(Url.Action("Method", "Controllers"))",
        });
    });
```

However when i try to use this i get the said error in a random empty space right above `$(document).ready(function() {` if i hard code out the ajax request in the spot where i am currently calling my plugin, everything works fine. Any ideas?

Edit:
worth noting this is my JS File call:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I then call my plugin file and the debugger shows me it is being properly included

Comment: this `"@(Url.Action("Method", "Controllers"))"` is not valid! also instead of `url: ContollerMethodLink,` you must write `url: settings.ContollerMethodLink,`

Comment: @AminJafari nice catch on the settings variable, though the `@url.Action` simply prints the relative url to whatever contoller/method i pass to it and im using that as the location of the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be well known problem with recent versions of Chrome. Using FF browser will provide with more detailed information about the error

Comment: This helped solve the problem, the issue was that two versions of jQuery were being included,